# network ansible command error: "msg": "network os centos is not supported"

Tags: ansible, yaml, centos, ssh, ansible-inventory

How do I get the `ansible` config for `rolly` below?

remote:

```
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core) 
Release:    8.2.2004
Codename:   Core
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.13
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/nsaunders/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ show config
bash: show: command not found...
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ ansible show config
usage: ansible [-h] [--version] [-v] [-b] [--become-method BECOME_METHOD]
               [--become-user BECOME_USER] [-K] [-i INVENTORY] [--list-hosts]
               [-l SUBSET] [-P POLL_INTERVAL] [-B SECONDS] [-o] [-t TREE] [-k]
               [--private-key PRIVATE_KEY_FILE] [-u REMOTE_USER]
               [-c CONNECTION] [-T TIMEOUT]
               [--ssh-common-args SSH_COMMON_ARGS]
               [--sftp-extra-args SFTP_EXTRA_ARGS]
               [--scp-extra-args SCP_EXTRA_ARGS]
               [--ssh-extra-args SSH_EXTRA_ARGS] [-C] [--syntax-check] [-D]
               [-e EXTRA_VARS] [--vault-id VAULT_IDS]
               [--ask-vault-pass | --vault-password-file VAULT_PASSWORD_FILES]
               [-f FORKS] [-M MODULE_PATH] [--playbook-dir BASEDIR]
               [-a MODULE_ARGS] [-m MODULE_NAME]
               pattern
ansible: error: unrecognized arguments: config
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$
```

local:

```
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ cat first_playbook.yml 
---

- name: Network Getting Started First Playbook
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: all
  tasks:

    - name: Get config for VyOS devices
      vyos_facts:
        gather_subset: all

    - name: Display the config
      debug:
        msg: "The hostname is {{ ansible_net_hostname }} and the OS is {{ ansible_net_version }}"
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ yamllint first_playbook.yml 
first_playbook.yml
  15:81     error    line too long (97 > 80 characters)  (line-length)

nicholas $ 
nicholas $ ansible all -i rolly.foo, -c network_cli -u nsaunders -k -m centos_facts -e ansible_network_os=centos
SSH password: 
rolly.foo | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "network os centos is not supported"
}
nicholas $
```

referencing:

https://www.ansible.com/blog/getting-started-writing-your-first-playbook

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to invalid value of `ansible_network_os:`

The playbook you try setup is meant for network devices.
And since centos is not a network device OS the playbook will fail.
Here you can find supported network OS.
[Ansible Documentation: ansible_network_os values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_index.html#settings-by-platform)

If you don't have any device running a supported network OS I recommend you to follow the regular user guide.
[Ansible User Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/index.html)

My suggestion is to setup a easy playbook that will run on the environment you have.
Get the understanding of following concepts.
`Control node`
`Managed nodes`
`Inventory`
`Modules`
`Tasks`
`Playbooks`

Here is a short example.
This will only execute `hostname` do confirm it execute on expected host.
Let's say `nicholas` is your control node and `rolly` is the managed node.

On `nicholas`:
Create a inventory as before with your control node and managed node.
inventory.txt:

```yaml
[local]
localhost ansible_connection=local

[managed_node]
rolly ansible_host=<rolly ip> ansible_user=<rolly user> ansible_ssh_pass=<rolly user password>
```

myplaybook.yml:

```yaml
---
- name: This will get hostname localy on control node
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: get hostname
      command: hostname
      register: result

    - name: print hostname
      debug:
          var: result

- name: This will get hostname remote on manged node
  hosts: rolly
  tasks:
    - name: get hostname
      command: hostname
      register: result

    - name: print hostname
      debug:
          var: result
```

And then execute on the control node:
`ansible-playbook -i inventory.txt myplaybook.yml`

Answer (score 0):

```
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
inventory = hosts
ask_vault_pass = True

[privilege_escalation]
become_ask_pass = True


nicholas $ 
nicholas $ sudo ansible-playbook first_playbook.yml --connection=local
BECOME password: 
Vault password: 
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/nicholas/ansible/hosts as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [Network Getting Started First Playbook] **************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************

nicholas $
```

As a [workaround to using](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/4365/23443) a remote, although it requires some additional configuration apparently.